# What anime is this character from?

Tags: story-identification, anime

Does anybody know who this character is and what anime he is from?

[image: Dark-haired light-skinned boy holds a sword upside-down. His eyes are blue except where overlaid by the sword, where they are red]

Comment: I have migrated this question here because I happen to know that it is from a fantasy anime, even though it may not necessarily look like it from the picture.

Comment: flowwww, be sure to join this SF&F stackexchange.  I thank @senshin for migrating the question here, where the rules are a little different, and identification questions are still considered on-topic.

Answer (score 24):

The characters depicted in the picture are blue-eyed Yato (holding the sword) and red-eyed Yukine in the reflection in the sword, two of the tri-tagonists from the anime series [Noragami](http://noragami.wikia.com/wiki/Yato).

[image]

The image itself is an original work by fan-artist [Haru](https://www.pixiv.net/member.php?id=2808787) titled [唯一無ニ](https://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=big&illust_id=41046025) ("*the only one*")

[image]

Comment: It is Yato, but you might also want to add that the character in the reflection of the blade is Yukine, since they aren't the same character and we aren't sure which character(s) OP meant.

Comment: @Pleiades - See edit. An excellent point

Answer (score 14):

This is Yato, the protagonist of [*Noragami*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/20507/Noragami). Here is an image from his [character information page](http://noragami-anime.net/chara/) on the anime's official website:

[image: Yato]

Answer (score 9):

This is two characters from [Noragami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noragami), superimposed.

The primary character depicted, who has black hair, blue eyes, and a ragged bib, is Yato (as mentioned by other answers).

[image]

In addition, the sword's reflection shows Yukine, who has blond hair, red eyes, and a (non-standard compound) kanji tattoo of sorts on his collarbone. Here's an image showing these physical traits:

[image]

The sword itself is also Yukine, in a way - several of the characters in this anime have both human-form and weapon-form manifestations, so it seems likely that the artist might have been trying to convey that duality by showing Yukine in the sword's reflection.

Comment: [Here](http://img05.drawr.net/draw/img/126602/52db9987qcd6FyTf.png) is a better view of the tattoo, which, for some reason. doesn't seem to be mirrored compared to the reflection.